# Unexpected EOF write error

Tags: unix, solaris, tar, tape, solaris-10

We have a Sun Solaris 10 server that is failing to backup using tar to write to tape.

```
tar cEf /dev/rmt/0cn .
```

The complete error is

```
tar: write error: unexpected EOF

tar error code 2
```

The directory is 652G and we are using LTO 4 tapes (800G/1600G).

I have Oracle support for this system which I've logged 2 tickets so far. The first ticket was resolved as the tape drive was at fault, which was promptly replaced. The second ticket is currently still open, the only response I've had is to update the st driver, which I've done.

I've tried tar using compression and without compression and both error. I can write small files within the target directory to tape.

Other things I've tried include reloading the tape drive, rebooting the server and using new tapes.

Comment: Include uname -a and a file on the tar command.  If you are using a 32-bit version of tar it may not be able to create an archive >2GB.

Comment: System is 64bit and has been working for a few years.